# use svg to create route in openstreetmap

Tags: java, svg, openstreetmap

I'd like to create routes in openstreetmap based on vector graphics (svg). A rather artistic approach. Given a specific path in the svg I want to find a region in openstreetmap where this particular path can be created. So actually I'm searching for a street-infrastructure that assembles the structure of the graphic. Assuming I've got the following svg: [SVG-Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fenFS.png)

The code of the svg looks like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="595.281px" height="841.891px" viewBox="0 0 595.281 841.891"
 enable-background="new 0 0 595.281 841.891" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10"
 d="M472.14,420.945h-137c0,0-61-54.5-75-68.5h-120v-76h332V420.945z" />
</svg>
```

How can I now use openstreetmap to find a route that assembles this structure? Any ideas how to proceed? Will I need leaflet or openlayers to accomplish this?

This task demands to read the svg-data first. I want to create the application in Java. Is Apache Batik the right tool to work with?

Any idea welcome!

Comment: Your question and your ultimate goal is unclear to me. Do you want to find a list of consecutive ways that matches the path of the SVG? Where in the world do you want to find it since the SVG doesn't provide any coordinates? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @scai: sorry for being late mate. Yes, that's absolutely right. I want to find a list of consecutive ways that match the path of the SVG. A SVG also contains coordinates, like the one above, but these ones, of course, do not correspond to the map. So I have to find a way in order to try to draw them on them map. This entire problem consists of many smaller ones. One main problem for me: How can I determine the angle between two streets? Any idea? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I think this problem is too complex to me for being able to help you. But I guess you will find better answers when re-asking at http://gis.stackexchange.com/.